# Yii query through multiple belongs to relationships

Tags: php, yii

I have the following tables:

**patient**

- id
- first_name
- last_name

**event**

- id
- patient_id
- event_description

**notification**

- id
- event_id
- notification_description

I have the following relations defined in my models:

**Notification.php**

```
public function relations()
{
    return array(
                'event' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Event', 'event_id'),
            );
}
```

**Event.php**

```
public function relations()
{
    return array(
                'patient' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Patient', 'patient_id'),
    );
}
```

I want to get all notifications for patient with first name "Joe" and last name "Smith".  Is there a way to do that without writing out an SQL statement?

Comment: yes, it is possible, that's how cgridview works

Comment: when you jump from event to notification, yu might need HAS_MANY

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need a custom search function, like:

```
    public function searchCandidates() {
// Warning: Please modify the following code to remove attributes that
// should not be searched.

        $criteria = new CDbCriteria;

        $criteria->with = array('candidate_relation');//this is a relation; you can pute here, relation_a.relation_b.relation_c
        $criteria->compare('id', $this->id);
        $criteria->compare('email', $this->email, true);
        $criteria->compare('password', $this->password);
        $criteria->compare('created', $this->created);
        $criteria->compare('lastmodified', $this->lastmodified);
        $criteria->compare('confirmed', $this->confirmed);
        $criteria->compare('is_candidate', 1);
        $criteria->compare('username', $this->username, true);
        $criteria->compare('candidate_relation.first_name', $this->full_name, true);//and another relation here ...
        $criteria->compare('candidate_relation.last_name', $this->full_name, true, 'OR');

        return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
            'criteria' => $criteria,
        ));
    }
```

where `full_name` is a custom property for the model: `public $full_name;`

Comment: Thanks.  Based on your advice, I used the following to get it to work. $criteria->with = array('event.patient'); $criteria->compare('patient.first_name',$this->search_string, true, 'OR'); $criteria->compare('patient.last_name',$this->search_string,true, 'OR');